# check the first rows date is in between the next rows date

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2014

Each row has a `DateEff` and a `DateExp`. Lets say I return 5 rows. I need to check the `DateEff` from the first row to see if it is in between the `DateEff` and `DateExp` of the second, third, fourth and fifth row and so on. I need to check every `DateEff` to make sure it is not between any rows `DateEff` and `DateExp`.

Here is a sample of what the data looks like.  As you can see, row 3 `DateEff` is (2013-03-30) and it is in between row 4 `DateEff` and `DateExp` and row 5`DateEff` and `DateExp.

Table

```
rowid  DateEff         DateExp
  1    1969-01-01      2012-09-30
  2    2012-10-01      2012-12-31 
  3    2013-03-30      2014-12-31 
  4    2013-01-01      2015-02-10 
  5    2013-01-01      2999-01-01
```

Results would look like this

```
 Prob Id    Problem Date    Affected Id   Aff Date Range
  3         2013-03-30         4          2013-01-01 - 2015-02-10
  3         2013-03-30         5          2013-01-01 - 2999-01-01
```

Comment: check the LAG function

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: SqlServer version is 2014

Comment: It should return the rows that are in between and what row it falls between, so in this case it should return row 3, dateEff  as problem an d  row 4, DateEff , DateExp as dateRange

Comment: jpw is correct i was just using one example( i thought to keep it simple) they should all be returned

Comment: not sure how to fomat this right now will try and fix it later Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
select 
    [Prob Id]        = t.rowid, 
    [Problem Date]   = t.DateEff,
    [Affected Id]    = a.rowid, 
    [Aff Date Range] = concat(a.DateEff,' - ',a.DateExp)
from tbl t -- your table is called tbl
outer apply 
(
    select * 
    from tbl -- your table is called tbl
    where t.DateEff between dateeff and DateExp and rowid > t.rowid
) a
where a.DateEff is not null
order by t.rowid, t.DateEff;
```

With your sample data this is the result:

```
Prob Id Problem Date    Affected Id Aff Date Range
3       2013-03-30      4           2013-01-01 - 2015-02-10
3       2013-03-30      5           2013-01-01 - 2999-01-01
4       2013-01-01      5           2013-01-01 - 2999-01-01
```

To get the exact output from your example (excluding row 4) change the condition in the apply to `t.DateEff > dateeff and t.DateEff < DateExp and rowid > t.rowid`. The output would then be:

```
Prob Id Problem Date    Affected Id Aff Date Range
3       2013-03-30      4           2013-01-01 - 2015-02-10
3       2013-03-30      5           2013-01-01 - 2999-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to itself to return overlapping pairs of rows:

```
Select a.RowID, a.DateEff as ProblemDate
, b.RowID as OverlapID, b.DateEff as OverlapStart, b.DateExp as OverlapEnd
from MyTable a
left join MyTable b
on a.RowID <> b.RowID
and a.DateEff <= b.DateExp
and a.DateEff >= b.DateEff
```

Comment: Thanks @APH this was helpful not the exact results I was looking for but did give me results i could use